# WCF with Duplex Communication

Tags: c#, wcf

Whenever I am using Window Forms It works Fine But it always give error with console applicion.

> Error- The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an
>   error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by
>   the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:01:00'.

Here is My Code

Contract

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IReportService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IReportServiceCallbak))]
    public interface IReportService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
        void ProcessReport();
    }

    public interface IReportServiceCallbak
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
        void Progress(int percentage);
    }
}
```

Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class ReportService : IReportService
    {

        public void ProcessReport()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IReportServiceCallbak>().Progress(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace DuplexClientsss
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Tests();

        }    }

    class Tests : ReportService.IReportServiceCallback
    {
        ReportService.ReportServiceClient obj;
        public Tests()
        {
             obj = new ReportService.ReportServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
             obj.ProcessReport();
        }
                public void Progress(int percentage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(percentage);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: **Note that the event-like behavior of duplex services only works within a session.** - found this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is almost certainly configuration related. Ensure the client system.serviceModel configuration is identical between the two service client libraries

Comment: I used same config for winForms and it is  working. but not with console application

Answer (score 0):

```
new Task
(
()=>
{
        obj.ProcessReport();
}
).Start();
```

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, that is fine, but please provide an adequate explanation of your solution. This answer makes absolutely no sense without some further discussion.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it worked but i assume that my previous code was causing deadlock because I was using only one thread